# Check if application went to background including by power button

Tags: android, background-process, lockscreen, onpause, taskmanager

How can I check if my application has gone to the background, including as a response to the power button?

I use this method when `onPause` is called:

```
private static boolean isApplicationBroughtToBackground(Context c) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
         ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
         String activeActivity = topActivity.getPackageName();
         String myActivity = c.getPackageName();
         L.e("Active : " + activeActivity + "  , MyActivity : " + myActivity);
         if (!activeActivity.equals(myActivity)) {
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and I call this method with 500ms delay to make sure the active task is changed.

The problem is that if you use the power button or other way to lock screen this method won't detect this.

How can I catch this scenario too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `onPause()` to detect screen lock

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (!isScreenOn) {

        // The screen has been locked 

    }
```

Comment: perfect . clean and exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

According to that lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html
you should check onStop instead of onPause